# Where does Messages.app store its "Play sound effects" setting?

Tags: macos, messages, settings, defaults, plist

I'm trying to write a script to configure the system and various apps to my liking, mostly via `defaults write`. I got stuck with Messages' *Play sound effects* setting (under General). I think this setting might be new in Mavericks.

I couldn't find it in any of the `*iChat*.plist` files under `~/Library/Preferences`, so I watched the whole directory for changes with FS events, and it doesn't seem like that setting is affecting any of the files in that directory.

Any ideas about other locations where Messages.app could be storing this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Messages.app is a sandboxed app, the preferences would be under `~/Library/Containers/`:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.plist
```

or look through `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.*iChat*/`.

Comment: Thanks to your hint I was able to find `Containers/com.apple.soagent/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.messageshelper.AlertsController.plist`. The resulting command to disable sounds is: `defaults write com.apple.messageshelper.AlertsController PlaySoundsKey -bool false`.